# Subtract number from matrix in R when condition holds

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix, subtraction

I know how to do some transformations to the table I read from file:

```
data = read.table(file, sep=" ", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=F)
data_transformed=cbind(data[, 1], round(
        data[, seq(from = 3, to = ncol(data), by = 3)] *100 /
        data[, seq(from = 2, to = ncol(data), by = 3)], digits=2))
```

And how to replace "Inf" by "0".

```
data_transformed[data_transformed==Inf] <- 0
```

Now, I need every number greater than 100 replace by (value-2*(value-100)) so that 130 will be replaced by 70 and 110 will be replaced by 90.

I am using following code, which does not work:

```
data_transformed[data_transformed>100] <- (data_transformed-2*(data_transformed-100))
```

Any suggestion how to fix it? Thank you very much.

I am getting this error:

```
Error in rowMeans(data_transformed, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: You don't have a reproducible problem here (and I do not see how `rowMeans` would have been called),  but I can tell you that you need to make sure that the vector on the RHS is exactly the length of the TRUE values of the condition expression inside `[.]`. It's probably also the case that you cannot do this correctly if that data.frame has any factor or character values ... so you do need to look at `str(data_transformed)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have copied the wrong error statement. It is very possible to get this warning:

```
Warning message:
In data_transformed[data_transformed > 100] <- data_transformed -  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

As it is mentioned in the comment by @IShouldBuyABoat. You have a filter `data_transformed > 100` on the LHS, but you do not have a filter on the RHS. See this code:

```
set.seed(1)
data <- matrix(round(rbinom(210, 3, .5) * 100), ncol = 21)
head(data)

data_transformed <- cbind(data[, 1],
  round(data[, seq(from = 3, to = ncol(data), by = 3)] * 100 /
        data[, seq(from = 2, to = ncol(data), by = 3)], digits = 2))
head(data_transformed)

data_transformed[data_transformed == Inf] <- 0
head(data_transformed)

a <- data_transformed > 100
a

# data_transformed[data_transformed > 100] <-
#   data_transformed - 2 * (data_transformed - 100)

data_transformed[a] <-
  data_transformed[a] - 2 * (data_transformed[a] - 100)

head(data_transformed)
```